How to enable SSR in nextjs14 + redux/toolkit + redux-persist?
I am trying to enable SSR in in Next.JS 14 + redux/toolkit + redux-persist but the whole page is not appearing inside the page source.
CODE:
layout.js
"use client";

import './globals.css';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import { Suspense, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import classes from './App.module.css';
import { CSRReduxProviders, SSRReduxProviders } from './_store/reduxProvider'
import Navbar from './_Layouts/navbar'
import Footer from './_Layouts/footer/Footer'
import { LoaderSkeleton } from './_components'
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'
import { AppProgressBar as ProgressBar } from 'next-nprogress-bar';
import Script from 'next/script';
import { HomePage, OffCanvasPopup } from './_components';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('Sustainable Products | Ecowiser');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname.includes('/search')) {
      setTitle(`${pathname.split('/').pop().replaceAll('%20', ' ').replaceAll('_', ' ').replaceAll('-', ' ')} | Ecowiser`);
    } else if (pathname.includes('/category')) {
      setTitle(`${pathname.split('/').pop().replaceAll('-', ' ')} | Ecowiser`);
    } else if (pathname.includes('/lux')) {
      setTitle(`Luxury Products | Ecowiser`);
    } else if (pathname.includes('/how-we-rate')) {
      setTitle("How We Rate | Ecowiser")
    } else if (pathname.split('/')[1].includes('-')) {
      setTitle(`${pathname.split('/').pop().split('-').slice(1).join(" ")} | Ecowiser`);
    }
  }, [pathname]);


  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content={'EcoWiser Products is a directory of sustainable products, helping consumers find eco-friendly items made from renewable resources and biodegradable materials.'} />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH}/icon.ico`} />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH}/icon.ico`} />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH}/apple-icon.png`} />
        <title>{title}</title>
      </head>
      <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        <Script
          id={"Skimlinks"}
          strategy="afterInteractive"
          src={`https://s.skimresources.com/js/263708X1748630.skimlinks.js`}
        />
        <Script
          id={"GoogleTagManager"}
          strategy="afterInteractive"
          src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}
        />
        <Script
          id={"GoogleAnalytics"}
          strategy="afterInteractive"
        >
          {`
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}', {
            page_path: window.location.pathname,
            });
          `}
        </Script>
        <Script
          id={"commento.io"}
          strategy="afterInteractive"
          defer
          src="https://ec2-44-219-132-22.compute-1.amazonaws.com/js/commento.js"
          data-auto-init="true"
        />
        <Script
          id={"kissmetrics-cdn"}
          strategy="afterInteractive"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            var _kmq = _kmq || [];
            var _kmk = _kmk || '8291a27d7270981e8c87dda4d684803f873c00e1';
            function _kms(u){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var d = document, f = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
                s = d.createElement('script');
                s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = u;
                f.parentNode.insertBefore(s, f);
            }, 1);
            }
            _kms('//i.kissmetrics.io/i.js');
            _kms('//scripts.kissmetrics.io/' + _kmk + '.2.js');
            `,
          }}
        />
        <ProgressBar
          height="4px"
          color="#025951"
          options={{
            showSpinner: false,
          }}
          shallowRouting
        />
        <Navbar />
        <Suspense fallback={<LoaderSkeleton />}>
          {typeof window !== 'undefined' ? (
            <CSRReduxProviders>
              {children}
            </CSRReduxProviders>
          ) : (
            <SSRReduxProviders>
              {children}
            </SSRReduxProviders>
          )}
        </Suspense>
        <Footer />
        <ToastContainer />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

"use client";

import { store, persistor } from './store.js';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export function CSRReduxProviders({ children }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        {children}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export function SSRReduxProviders({ children }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  );
}

All elements inside {children} do not appear inside the page source.
Is there any way to make the whole page visible inside the page source?
I have tried conditionally rendering the {children} based on the typeof window, but it is not working, apart from the navbar and footer nothing else appears on the page source, not even the page heading.

https://github.com/antokhio/next-rtk-remember
